# JSON navigating

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi I have a JSON Deserialized with NewstonSoft JSon.NET to a string var wich looks like :

```
data = {"123456789": [{
"queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"name": "Karthus's Captains",
"entries": [{
  "leaguePoints": 37,
  "isFreshBlood": false,
  "isHotStreak": false,
  "division": "I",
  "isInactive": false,
  "isVeteran": true,
  "losses": 124,
  "playerOrTeamName": "Nickname",
  "playerOrTeamId": "123456789",
  "wins": 136
}],
"tier": "SILVER"
}]}
```

And I would like to know how can i access the leaguePoints for example which is inside "entries". Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to access a special entry to assign iut to a var, not to create a special class

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deserialize the JSON into concrete classes (as asked in [this quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028532/parse-the-json-response-in-c-sharp)), you can use JSON.NET's [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)-class like this:

```
string jsonData = GetJsonStringFormSomewhere();
var jObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

var idOrWhatever = jObject["123456789"].First();
var firstEntry = idOrWhatever["entries"].First();
var leaguePoints = firstEntry["leaguePoints"].Value<int>();
```

Comment: Is it possible to deserialize to a Dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this with Newtonsoft.  One way without serialising to a whole object might be such as this;

```
    JToken first = JObject.Parse(data);
    JArray res = (JArray)first.SelectToken("123456789");
    JToken entries = (JToken)JObject.Parse(res[0].ToString());
    JArray result = JArray.Parse(entries.SelectToken("entries").ToString());

    int leaguePoints = (int)result[0].SelectToken("leaguePoints");
```

I done this quickly and split it down into line by line so you can see each step but it means that it is not very elegant, you can of course concatenate this or use linq to get to your data.

Comment: Please note, that the additional invocations of `Parse` aren't necessary (it's actually redundant) as the whole object is already parsed in your first line. So instead of doing `JToken entries = (JToken)JObject.Parse(res[0].ToString());` you can simply do `JToken entries = res[0];`. This applies for the next line of your listing, too.